# Android - Notification Pending Intent - Add to top of activity stack issue

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, activity-stack

I'm a bit confused with pending intents in the notification builder. I've got a `MainActivity` activity and a `MessageList` activity. I have a service to show a notification when a new message in found, and I want it to be that if the user presses the notification it opens to the `MessageList` activity but when they press back they will return to the activity they were in.

Essentially I want to add `MessageList` activity to the top of the activity stack when they press the notification without modifying the current activity stack.

Thank you

Comment: OK. So what have you done already? Are you having a problem? What are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I got it to work with some old code I wrote a while back. This does what I wanted -

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AlertListActivity.class);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```